# How to make a request override a polling request

Tags: htmx

I have a table on a page that that automatically updates every second, like this:

```
<div class="table" hx-post="/table.php" hx-trigger="load, every 1s"></div>
```

I also have a button that can move to a specific position in the table, like this:

```
<button hx-post="/table.php" hx-target=".test" hx-vals='{"position": "100"}'>100</button>
```

This works, as I want the table to keep updating every second even after clicking the button.

However, sometimes when I click the button it may "collide" with the automatic `every 1s` refresh that the table is doing. So either the button won't do anything, or it will move to the new position in the table, but then be overridden by the `every 1s` request that was taking place at the time.

It works fine most of the time, but if I click the button whilst the table is refreshing it doesn't work as I'd like.

Is there any way to make the button click take precedence over the `every 1s` request? So even if the `every 1s` request is being processed, the button request overrides it?

Comment: use `drop` or `abort` of `hx-sync` on the button? https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-sync/